# Problema al actualizar repositorios en Kali Linux, no puedo acceder a https://http.kali.org/kali/

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

Estoy experimentando dificultades al intentar actualizar los repositorios en Kali Linux. Cuando ejecuto sudo apt update, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://http.kali.org/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not connect to 

http.kali.org:443 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not connect to http.kali.org:80 (192.99.200.113), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Lo que me parece extraño es que no puedo acceder a https://http.kali.org/kali/ a través de mi navegador, isolo cuando uso el navegador top puedo acceder al sitio. Esto me lleva a pensar que la página https://http.kali.org/kali/ podría estar bloqueada o inaccesible desde mi ubicación.

No tengo la opción de utilizar un VPN para solucionar este problema, ya que mi objetivo es precisamente actualizar la lista de repositorios en Kali Linux.

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia sobre cómo puedo resolver este problema y actualizar los repositorios en Kali Linux si no puedo acceder a https://http.kali.org/kali/?

Comment: ¿Accedes a algo en internet? Si no recuerdo mal, tienes que actualizar un controlador wifi cuando empiezas a usar Kali.